# Groovy script for Json to CSV conversion

Tags: json, groovy

I need to convert the below json to CSV using groovy script. My input Json is below

```
[{
"id":1,
"campaign":
{
"cost":0,
"name":"Test1"
},
"visitorId":3
},
{
"id":2,
"campaign":
{
"cost":0,
"name":"Test2"
},
"visitorId":5
}]
```

and i need the out put in the below csv format

```
id,cost,name,visitorID
1,0,Test1,3
2,0,Test2,5
```

I am using below groovy script but it gives a different output

```
def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper();
def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String)
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
object.each{
    sb << it.collect{ it.value }
            .join(",")
            .concat("\n")}
message.setBody(sb.toString())
```

Any guidance would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `object` is a List of nested Maps. If you want it to be kind of generic and you can rely on this specific structure you could try something like

```
def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
List<Map> object = jsonSlurper.parseText(message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String)
List<List<Map.Entry>> rows = object.collect{ Map map -> map.collectMany{ k, v -> v instanceof Map ? v.entrySet() : [Map.entry(k, v)] } }
List header = rows.first().collect { it.key }
List<List> body = rows.collect { row -> row.collect { it.value } }
String csvOutput = ([header] + body).collect { List row -> row.join(",") }.join("\n")
```

but you better listen to chubbsondubs' advice.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to be able to just generically write a JSON to CSV converter because JSON has hierarchy and CSV is a flat table.  So you'll have to get specific:

```
new File("objects.csv").withPrintWriter { writer ->
   writer.println("id,cost,name,visitorID")
   objects.each { row ->
      writer.println( "${row.id},${row.campaign.cost},${row.campaign.name},${row.visitorId}" )
   }
}
```

To make it more generic or higher level you'll have to make situation specific assumptions to make less typing.  But it won't work for all JSONs so unless the example you gave is exactly what you are trying to write out you'll have to think harder about your situation.

Word to the wise you're not using a CSV writing library which without it means your are not handling the harder parts of CSV like escaping, quoting, etc.  My suggestion is DO NOT write your own version of CSV creation code.  Go get a CSV library to help you.